# Problem With ColorScheme

Tags: colorscheme

I am a vim user looking for help for a problem with my vim colorscheme. When I start everything looks fine and is usable until I start scrolling down. Once I scroll the background takes on the color of the terminal background.

The terminal I use is gnome-terminal on Fedora 24

To show the clear difference I made my gnome terminal clear.

In Vim Before Scroll: 
[image]

After Scroll: 
[image]

Here's my .vimrc and its setup to be simple hopefully :D

https://github.com/TheGalacticNinja/vimrc/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: can you link to your vimrc for more information. Also try :set  t_Co=256

Comment: Are you using any terminal multiplexer? What's the value of `$TERM`?

Comment: please link to .vimrc ! or try to use urxvt and see if the problem persists !

Comment: Also how is urxvt...Ive been thinking of switiching over to using that for my linux machines?

Comment: @Robbie I can tell a lot about urxvt, but I want you to use and then tell about how good it is, because everyone has different preferences. The main why I switched is the speed.

Comment: @Robbie I had downloaded your .vimrc and it worked perfectly on my linux box except that i didnt have the colorscheme :D  , so maybe there's some problem with gnome-terminal

Comment: Try [following these steps](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
set t_ut=
```

to ~/.vimrc

I had the same issue on Debian 9 with Gnome Terminal and Mate Terminal, and on some Fedora and Centos virtual machines where I did not have GUI installed. Adding this line solved the problem.

Comment: Note that your answer has been automatically flagged as low quality due to the length of its content. I will not delete it as it tries to answer the question but it would be more useful for OP and for future readers if you added some explanations about what this setting does and why OP would want to use it in this case.

Comment: @Robbie `t_ut` is 'clearing uses the current background color', so if nothing else it's worth running `:set t_ut` to see how it's currently set.